# How to select all rows from a created filter in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this telerik project: https://dojo.telerik.com/@blockbaster/axIbuPOs

**Test it:**

1. Enter the value "15" in the "Units in Stock" column.

   --> 4 elements should appear as a result over 2 pages.
2. Click on the "Select all rows"-checkbox in the upper left corner

   --> only the visible elements are added

`The selected product ids are: [26, 7]`

**Goal:** Perform point 1-2

`The selected product ids are: [26, 48, 7, 70]`

When exporting to Excel from the grid, there is the option:

```
excel: {
  allPages: true
}
```

Is there an option for this, too?

Note: There is no server paging yet. All data will be loaded at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic steps are:

1. Set the persistSelection configuration of the Grid to true.
2. Use a jQuery selector to subscribe for the click event of the master checkbox.
3. In the click event handler

   3.1 Save the current page size in a global variable by using the pageSize method of the Kendo UI dataSource.

   3.2 Show all the rows on a single page by using the pageSize method.

   3.3 Select all the rows by using the select method of the Kendo UI Grid.

   3.5 Bring back the old page size by using the pageSize method.

   function onClick(e) {
           var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

   ```
       oldPageSize = grid.dataSource.pageSize();
       grid.dataSource.pageSize(grid.dataSource.data().length);

       if (grid.dataSource.data().length === grid.select().length) {
           grid.clearSelection();
       } else {
           grid.select("tr");
       };

       grid.dataSource.pageSize(oldPageSize);
   };
   ```

Telerik have an example of selection across grid pages in the docs [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/checkbox-selection-select-all-rows-all-pages)